# Using robocopy /NP writes odd sequence around percentage

Tags: cmd, robocopy

I am using robocopy with /NP and capturing stdout and stderr using >>log.txt 2>&1. I am copying all files from the "Outbound" directory to an "Archive" directory.

```
robocopy "%PNAME%\Outbound" "%ARCHIVE_PATH%" * /NP /MT:32
```

The output appears to contain character sequences that are classic problems with DOS vs. UNIX line endings.

```
New File            3381    DIM_DATE_CCYYMM.txt^M  0%  ^M100%
New File          340759    DIM_DATE_CCYYMMDD_PAID_DT.txt^M100%
New File          340730    DIM_DATE_CCYYMMDD_SVC_DT.txt^M100%
```

Looking into the log file, there are indeed instances of 0x0D which are not followed by 0x0A. Is this just the way Microsoft envisioned the output? Can I do anything to change it short of manipulating the log file post-production?

```
000670    64    5c    0d    0a    09    20    20    20    20    4e    65    77    20    46    69    6c
         d   \  \r  \n  \t                   N   e   w       F   i   l
000680    65    20    20    09    09    20    20    20    20    33    33    38    31    09    44    49
         e          \t  \t                   3   3   8   1  \t   D   I
000690    4d    5f    44    41    54    45    5f    43    43    59    59    4d    4d    2e    74    78
         M   _   D   A   T   E   _   C   C   Y   Y   M   M   .   t   x
0006a0    74    0d    20    20    30    25    20    20    0d    31    30    30    25    20    20    0d
         t  \r           0   %          \r   1   0   0   %          \r
0006b0    0a    09    20    20    20    20    4e    65    77    20    46    69    6c    65    20    20
        \n  \t                   N   e   w       F   i   l   e
```

Comment: `0x0D` is a carriage return (like on typewriter pushing the waggon back to the right without turning the waltz = without linefeed). That's the way to overwrite (change) the previously written line. That's working fine on the screen, but doesn't on files (the disk can't "push back the waggon" - in other words, those control characters are a feature of the terminal/screen (respective it's "driver")).

Comment: When /NP (no progress) was specified, robocopy should have not done anything about pushing any kind of transportation backward. /NP means "don't do that funky terminal stuff." Why would Microsoft deliver this?

Comment: hm - your line doesn't show any percentages for me - neither on screen nor in logfile. If I *remove* `/NP`, then I get the same type of output as you (like I would expect)

Comment: That odd percentage progress appears for me only if the `/MT` switch is present (_Windows 8.1_); @Stephan what Windows version are you running? There is a bit unclear note _The `/MT` parameter applies to Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7_ although `robocopy` reference should apply to _Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows 8_ (and Windows 10 as well, of course).

Comment: @JosefZ - I think you are correct. The malformed line ending bytes do not appear if the /MT parameter is not used. The problem is on Windows Server 2008 R2, but not on Windows 10. Microsoft bug.